# Specific Li-po, Li-ion and charging facts (low intensity, slow)

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, lipo, best-practice, battery-lifespan

I have the following battery, but not its original charger:

- 12 V, 4.0 Ah
- Cell Balancing Longer Battery Life Increased Battery Lifespan. Higher Battery Resources Due To Evenly Used Cells.

BTW internally it has 6 cells, so 2 packs in parallel

I will charge with a generic charger Imax B6 that has a display to monitor the voltage.

By default the closest to 12 V option offered by the charger is a predefined 11.1 V / 0.5 A

I am aware that c1 (4 A) is recommended and not bad for life span, but as I am not in a hurry I can charge at any rate as far as it increases the life span.

So 0.5 A is C/8, seems too small a rate and slow. Can 0.5 A be bad or worse than a 1 A (C/4) or 2 A (C/2)?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not aware of any disadvantages of slower charging, generally it improves battery life and increases the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

11.1V is a 3-cells battery at a selling or storage with a half-charge. Half-charge produces fairly low capacity. It should be 12.6V when fully charged.

Battery life is very long when a Lithium rechargeable battery cell is at half-charge and is rarely discharged to 3.0V per cell.